# Get all object properties in ontology without using reasoner

Tags: owl-api

In OWL API, there method `getObjectPropertiesInSignature()` can be used to obtain the set of object properties in an ontology. I have two questions with respect to this:

1. By using this method, will it return also the object properties in imported ontology ?
2. Also, this method is deprecated in the latest version of OWL API, is there another method with the same behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

`getObjectPropertiesInSignature()` has an overloaded version with a boolean flag, its purpose is to allow you to choose to look in the signature of the ontology or in the signature of the imports closure. Use it to get the object properties for the whole imports  closure.

The method is deprecated and the javadoc suggests using the stream based method. For all such scenarios in OWLAPI 5, methods named `getXxx()` have an alternative version named `xxx()` that returns a stream. It is preferable to use them if you need only one iteration through the underlying collection (it saves having to make defensive copies). If you need multiple iterations or lookups, you can keep using the deprecated methods or collect the data from the stream in a set.